# order by in linq with multiple scenarios

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have to order the following by contractor name with the following logic: first the columns that are parents followed by their children.

[image]

For example here in the image, I want this result:

1. the first row should be *Panhandle Mental Health Ctr/Region 1* because it is the first parent (in alphabetic order);
2. the second row should be *Panhandle Medical Health Center - Sidney* because it is the first child in alphabetic order;
3. the third row should be *Region 1 - Panhandle Prevention Coalition*
4. the next rows should be the next parent, followed by his children and so on.

I have tried something like this so far, I am sure it's not correct approach, and it is still not satisfying all scenarios.

```
.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.ContractorName.Split(' ').First()).ThenBy(p=>p.ParentName).ToList<ContractModel.providers>()
```

Comment: Do you have one level of parent/child or multiple levels?  if multiple levels you need a recursive methiod.

Comment: just one level of parent/child

Comment: This acts as I would expect from the code, what is it that's wrong with the list that is shown there?

Comment: this doesnt really make sense in terms of sorting data

Comment: I want the parent records on top and child records of that parent should follow that parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain what you are looking for you need to do as follows:

```
.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(p => p.IsParent)
    .OrderBy(p => p.ContractorName)
    .SelectMany(p =>
        {
            // You will return this list
            var list = new List<YourType>();
            // First you add the parent
            list.Add(p);
            // Then you add all the children ordered by name 
            // (I assume you can get them via a relation)
            list.AddRange(p.Children.OrderBy(c => c.ContractorName).ToList());
            // Finally you return the list
            return list;
        }).ToList();
```

The logic here is to first extract the records that are parents and then concatenate all his children. The `SelectMany` will do the trick to return a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an CompareTo method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Contractors> contractors = new List<Contractors>() {
                new Contractors() { ContractorName = "Panhandle Mental Health Center - Sidney", ParentName = "Panhandle Mental Health Ctr/Region 1"},
                new Contractors() { ContractorName = "Panhandle Mental Health Center - Sidney", ParentName = "Panhandle Mental Health Ctr/Region 1"},
                new Contractors() { ContractorName = "Panhandle Mental Health Ctr/Region 1"},
                new Contractors() { ContractorName = "Region 1 - Panhandle Prevention Coalition", ParentName = "Panhandle Mental Health Ctr/Region 1"},
                new Contractors() { ContractorName = "Region 1 Behavioral Health - Ave. D. Scottsbluff",ParentName = "Region 1 Behaviorial Health Authority"},
                new Contractors() { ContractorName = "Region 1 Behavioral Health Authority"},
                new Contractors() { ContractorName = "Region 1 Behavioral Health Authority - 16 St Scottsbluff", ParentName = "Region 1 Behaviorial Health Authority"},
            };
            contractors.Sort((x,y) => x.CompareTo(y));
        }
    }
    public class Contractors : IComparable< Contractors>
    {
        public string ContractorName { get; set; }
        public string ParentName { get; set; }


        public int CompareTo(Contractors contractor)
        {
            if (this.ContractorName == null || this.ContractorName.CompareTo(contractor.ContractorName) == 1)
                return 1;
            if (contractor.ContractorName == null || this.ContractorName.CompareTo(contractor.ContractorName) == -1)
                return -1;
            if (this.ParentName == null || this.ParentName.CompareTo(contractor.ParentName) == 1)
                return 1;
            if (this.ParentName == null || this.ParentName.CompareTo(contractor.ParentName) == -1)
                return -1;
            return 0;

        }

    }

}
​
```